# Flash CC appendText() does not insert whole text to the dynamic text

Tags: flash, appendtext, flash-cc

I have noticed strange problem while using the appendText() method. It seems to work work as it should, but in some cases it does not paste whole text to the dynamic text. This code is working good for "Windows 7", but for "Windows 8" it shows: "Windows ". No matter how many "8" I put in this code, it will always disappears - if I write in second case: "Windows 88887" I get "Windows 7".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is it a bug in Flash CC?

I have this error in a few other dynamic texts - usually one letter or number disappears.

```
if (windowsIsChosen) {
    Text.OS.appendText("Windows");
    switch (whichWindows) {
        case 1: Text.OSVersion.appendText("Windows 7");
        break;
        case 2: Text.OSVersion.appendText("Windows 8");
        break;
        default: Text.OSVersion.appendText("Not chosen");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have defined that particular textfield to embed font, but for whatever reason, the font for '8' is not being embedded. Change the font embedding properties of that textfield, it may fix it.

This can happen if you have Windows 7 by default in the textfield, so it will embed W,i,n,d,o,w,s,7 characters, but not any others.

Comment: I have embedded the font previously, but when I embedded this font once more - it working as it should. Thank you for help.